# Proof that an hyperboloid is an open set in $\mathbb{R}^3$.

Tags: calculus, vectors

Let $S=\{ (x,y,z) \in \mathbb{R}^3 | z^2-x^2-y^2-1>0 \}$. Proof that $S$ is an open set.

I'm trying to prove it as follows:

By definition, I need to proof that $\forall u \in S, \exists B_{r} (u) \subset S$ for some $r>0$.

Let $u=(a,b,c) \in S. \iff c^2-a^2-b^2-1>0.$

Then, I tried to find a radius $r>0$ such that there's an open ball centered in $u$ with radius $r$ in many ways (for example, finding the minimun value of $||u-v||$ where $v \in \partial S$), but I was unsuccesfully.

Can someone help me with this?

Comment: Note that $P(a, b, c) = c^2 - a^2 - b^2 - 1$ is a polynomial, and hence is continuous. Therefore, $S = P^{-1}(0, \infty)$ is open.

Comment: Alternatively, if $c^2 - a^2 - b^2 - 1 > 0$, then $c^2 - a^2 - b^2 - 1 > \epsilon$ for some $\epsilon > 0$. Choose $\delta$ very small so that $|c^2 - (c \pm \delta)^2| < \epsilon / 3$, and likewise for $a$ and $b$. What can you conclude from this? Note that this gives a reduction to a (much easier) one-dimensional problem.